# Mathematical expression of the coordinate exchange operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, exchange-interaction

So I know that the total exchange operator is the product of the coordinate, spin and isospin exchange operators, as,

\begin{equation}
P_{12} = P_{12}^r P_{12}^\sigma P_{12}^\tau
\end{equation}

The coordinate $P_{12}^r$, spin $P_{12}^\sigma$ and isospin $P_{12}^\tau$ exchange operators are introduced according to,

\begin{align}
P_{12}^r |r_1 \sigma_1 q_1, r_2 \sigma_2 q_2 \rangle = |r_2 \sigma_1 q_1, r_1 \sigma_2 q_2 \rangle \\
P_{12}^\sigma |r_1 \sigma_1 q_1, r_2 \sigma_2 q_2 \rangle = |r_1 \sigma_2 q_1, r_2 \sigma_1 q_2 \rangle \\
P_{12}^\tau |r_1 \sigma_1 q_1, r_2 \sigma_2 q_2 \rangle = |r_1 \sigma_1 q_2, r_2 \sigma_2 q_1 \rangle
\end{align}

Furthermore, the spin and isospin exchange operators can be expressed as,

\begin{align}
P_{12}^\sigma = \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sigma_1 \cdot \sigma_2 )\\
P_{12}^\tau = \frac{1}{2} (1 + \tau_1 \cdot \tau_2)
\end{align}

However, I don't know the expression of the coordinate exchange operator. How can it be expressed?

Comment: The expression will never be as simple, because it acts on an infinite dimensional space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a formal wisecrack: you know how to Lagrange-shift functions,
$$
e^{a\partial_x + b\partial_y} f(x,y)=f(x+a,y+b),
$$
a mere rewriting of the Taylor expansion.

You may  further perform two evaluations in an important order,
$$
  f(x+a,y+b)   \Big|^{x=0}_{y=0}= f(a,b),
$$
and
$$
  f(a,b)   \Big|^{a=y}_{b=x}= f(y,x),
$$
so that
$$
P^r_{12} f(x,y)= \left( \left((e^{a\partial_x + b\partial_y} f(x,y) ) \Big|^{x=0}_{y=0} \right ) \Bigg|^{a=y}_{b=x} \right)  =f(y,x)
$$
so, hyper-formally,
$$
P^r_{12}=\Big|^{a=y}_{b=x}  \circ \Big|^{x=0}_{y=0}  \circ e^{a\partial_x + b\partial_y} .
$$
This is an infinite-dimensional representation, so its exchange operator is predictably  messier than for the other two finite-dimensional representations you exchanged. Not clear to me what you might do with it...